# A program that will input string and converts all uppercase characters to lower case and vice-versa. All non-alpha characters stays the same

Tags: assembly, x86, console-application, masm, masm32

I'm new to masm32 programming, and I am having a hard time understanding how the flows works

```
.data
ask DB "Enter Input Here: ", 0


.data?
conversion DB 100 dup(?)



.code

start:

    Push Offset ask
    Call StdOut

    Push 100
    Push Offset conversion
    Call StdIn

    sub ecx, ecx

setCounter:
    lea ebx, conversion
    mov al, [ebx+ecx]
    .IF ebx != 0
        inc ecx
    .ELSE
        jmp conv
    .ENDIF

    jmp setCounter

strLen:
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx, 0
    je printOut
conv:
    cmp al, 97
    jge checkLimit
    cmp al, 65
    jge checkLimit
    cmp al, 0
    je terminate

toLow:
    add al, 32
    stosb
    jmp strLen

toHigh:
    sub al, 32
    stosb
    jmp strLen

checkLimit:
    cmp al, 91
    jl toLow
    cmp al, 123
    jl toHigh
    stosb
    jmp strLen

printOut:
    push offset conversion          
    call StdOut                 


terminate:

    invoke ExitProcess,0

end start
```

It is expected to have an output of
`"SSss%$ 23@ssSS"` from input
`"ssSS%$ 23@SSss`

Comment: I wrote an asm function that does this efficiently on a different Q&A: [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](//stackoverflow.com/a/35936844).  You only need to decide if it's alphabetic, and if so XOR with 32, regardless of whether it's upper or lower case.  That allows the branching to be simpler.  (See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54536362))

Comment: Is there a question here?  From a quick look, this code has some of the right constants and might work.  If so, what kind of answer are you looking for?  If not, then edit it to make a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes the code doesn't work on me... after I enter an input, the program crashes.
From what I think, my code has a problem on how I store the modified string. And I can't still identify what to be done. By the way thanks for the comment/help

Comment: Then edit your question to make it a [mcve], including what you see with a debugger: which instruction crashes, and what's in registers at the time.  (vs. what you expected to be there).

Answer (score 1):

> after I enter an input, the program crashes

---

> ```
>     sub ecx, ecx
>   setCounter:
>     lea ebx, conversion
>     mov al, [ebx+ecx]
>     .IF ebx != 0
>         inc ecx
>     .ELSE
>         jmp conv
>     .ENDIF
>     jmp setCounter
> ```

This is an infinite loop!

The condition `.IF ebx != 0` always evaluates to TRUE and thus the counter increments endlessly.